# RegEx for extracting a few <div> tags

Tags: java, regex, perl

Here's the input String:

```
<div class="matchthis">Orange</div>
<div class="dontmatch">One</div>
<div class="matchthis" id="hurdle">Lemon</div>
<div class="dontmatch">Two</div>
<div id="hurdle" class="matchthis">Peach</div>
```

I want to output below **(all `<div>` tags containing `class="matchthis"`)**:

```
<div class="matchthis">Orange</div>
<div class="matchthis" id="hurdle">Lemon</div>
<div id="hurdle" class="matchthis">Peach</div>
```

This Java RegEx **`<div class=\"matchthis\">(.*?)(?=</div>)`** will only output the following:

```
<div class="matchthis">Orange</div>
```

Please help improve the RegEx to get the desired output.

Please do not tell me to use slower DOM/Soup/etc. I wonder if raw regex can solve the simple problem above (you'll be awarded for the answer!). Yes I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) so don't even mention it.

Comment: How can this be both java _and_ perl?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: `Please do not tell me to use slower DOM... ` Given that this is your third consecutive question asking the same thing with small variations, I wonder if would accept other suggestion: try to understand why the previous answers work (try to learn regex), instead of keeping asking and asking.

Comment: @Martijn I already linked to that thread in my original post. I'm well aware of the controversity of using regex in XML. However unlike you, others have helped me find a solution and I'm very happy to use regex successfully in XML.

Comment: Take note of your `...tchthis\">(.*?)...`.  You desire ending brace of tag start right after `"matchthis"`.

Comment: @leonbloy I understand RegEx fairly well now and although my question here looks very similar to my previous question, the solution is very different. I wasn't able to figure this out -> (?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')* <-on my own with ease, so I'm glad to have posted this problem online. Those who helped were also awarded with upvotes. Now go away.

Comment: @slashline it's not a mater of "controversy".  It's a matter of tool purpose and features.  You can try all you like, but a hammer is not the right tool to put a screw into wood...even if you CAN hit it just hard enough to make it go in anyway.

Comment: @Robert P. Understood. I'll still consider an XML parser, but this solution appears to be faster. Almost 3 months later it is still working very effectively with >1000 pageviews daily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern.compile(
   "<div class=\"matchthis\"(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*>(.*?)(?=</div>)",
   Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL)
```

To break it down,

```
 (?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*
```

matches any number of the below due to the

```
 (?: ... )*
```

of non-quote non-tag closers due to

```
[^>\"']
```

or double quoted attribute values

```
\"[^\"]*\"
```

or single quoted attribute values

```
'[^']*'
```

The `Pattern.DOTALL` means that your `.*?` will allow newlines in the `div` body.

The `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` causes it to handle case folding of HTML element names properly, though if your default locale is Turkish you might get some weirdness around `<DİV>` (note the dotted I).

Comment: don't you miss `<div id="hurdle" class="matchthis">Peach</div>
`?

Comment: @Atreys I forgot to mention that I added `(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*` immediately after `<div`

Answer (score 3):

If tags cannot be nested, this is possible.

You can add `(?:\s+\w+=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\S*))*` to both sides of your attribute.

Do not assume that this is any faster than a good parser.

Comment: This gave me an error in Java. I don't think \S is accepted. I appreciate the help though. Accepted a different answer.

Comment: @Slash: You need to escape the backslash from the string by writing `\\S`

Answer (score 0):

`<div [^>]*class=\"matchthis\"[^>]*>(.*?)(?=</div>)`